# What are the differences of TouchEvent constants?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, touch-event

What is the difference between TOUCH_BEGIN, TOUCH_OVER and TOUCH_ROLL_OVER in the TouchEvent for AS3?

I'm trying to find the correct one to use for an "on-tap"/while tapping state, and also one for after the button has been "tapped".

Answer (score 0):

Count `TOUCH_BEGIN` as touchpad's `MOUSE_DOWN` version, with an additional parameter - the index of the touching point (0-based), so that you won't mix up touch events. `TOUCH_END` is the touchpad's `MOUSE_UP`, `TOUCH_ROLLOVER` is roughly mapped to `MOUSE_DOWN` condition and `MOUSE_OVER` event at once.